# Flash fullscreen video appearing stretched in portrait mode on Android 4.0.4 (Ice Cream Sandwich)

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, galaxy, samsung-mobile

I noticed that when I tried playing a Flash video in fullscreen mode on a Galaxy Nexus S running Android 4.0.4 (ICS), if I were in portrait mode, the video would appear stretched vertically.

I tried setting a specific width and height for the video:

```
this.m_player.setActualSize(640, 360);
```

The weird thing is that when the player first goes fullscreen in portrait mode, it will always appear stretched, but if I rotate to landscape and then rotate back to portrait mode again, the player will be the size that I specified.  So it seems like the player is ignoring any specific size I set for it when the player first loads.

Has anyone experienced this on a Samsung Galaxy Nexus S phone running Android before?  Is there a workaround for this behavior?

I'm more of a Javascript person so I'm not overly familiar with Actionscript, but it would be great to know that I'm not the only person that has seen this behavior with Flash videos on Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it turns out that simply adding the following to the Flash embed code will make it render only in landscape mode, preventing it from switching to portrait mode and appearing "stretched."

For some reason setting the fullScreenAspectRatio in the AS3 code itself did not seem to work, but this did:

```
<param name="fullScreenAspectRatio" value="landscape">
```